# MIPS - Reading double from stack

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I have problems with MIPS. I can store and write floats on the stack without any problems. But If I try to do the same thing with a double, the following message appears:

```
Error in line 12: Runtime exception at 0x0040001c: address not aligned on doubleword boundary 0x7fffeff4
#Line12:# 
ldc1 $f12, 0($sp)       #   Pop from stack
```

This is my code

```
.data
    test: .double 22.75
.text
.globl main
main:
    l.d $f4, test       #   Value to $f4
    mfc1 $t0,$f4        #   $f4 to $t0
    addi $sp, $sp, -8   #   Decrease SP
    sw $t0, 4($sp)      #   Store first word
    mfc1 $t0,$f5        #   $f5 to $t0
    sw $t0, 0($sp)      #   Store second word
    ldc1 $f12, 0($sp)       #   Pop from stack
    li $v0, 3       #   Call API StdOut
    syscall         #   Print result
    li $v0, 10      #   Call API
    syscall         #   End of program
```

I don't really know what to do. Am I using the wrong function to restore the double value?

Comment: As the error message says, you need to align `$sp`. It's only aligned to 4 bytes by default not 8.

Comment: Related: [Why does the MIPS stack pointer need to be kept double word aligned?](//stackoverflow.com/q/39786943) - mainstream OSes like Linux and IRIX do choose to keep `$sp` aligned by 8 as part of the calling convention, even on 32-bit-only MIPS.  So normal functions don't need AND the stack pointer to get proper alignment for a `double`.  But you can see how clang implements `_Alignas(16)`, which it can't get for free: https://godbolt.org/z/qckeYd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jester mentioned:

```
ldc1 $f12, -4($sp)       #   Pop from stack
```

worked, but

```
l.d $f4, test
mfc1 $t0,$f4
addi $sp, $sp, -16
andi $sp, $sp, 0xFFFFFFF8
sw $t0, 8($sp)
mfc1 $t0,$f5
sw $t0, 0($sp)
ldc1 $f12, 0($sp) # Pop from stack
```

does fix the error, but the value written in $f12 is not correct. 
22.75 turns into 5.322717027E-315.

I figured it out.

```
mfc1.d  $t0,$f4
```

instead of

```
mfc1 $t0,$f4
```

solved the problem.

Comment: That's not a general solution: Nothing guarantees that `$sp - 4` is 8-byte aligned.  That's how things happened to work out in your program.  Also, unless the calling convention has a red-zone, it's not safe to use space below `$sp` - it could be asynchronously clobbered at any time.  (So you need to `addi $sp, $sp, -16` / `andi $sp, $sp, 0xFFFFFFF8` or something to get 8-byte aligned storage on a stack that has 4-byte alignment, with a unknown offset from 8-byte alignment (either 0 or 4 bytes away).  But MIPS ANDI zero-extends its immediate, so it only works as a pseudo-instruction...

Comment: in your update, you still aren't ANDing to mask off the low bits.  You're just assuming that `$sp - 4` is 8-byte aligned (which happens to be true for this function the way you're running it), or in the version that doesn't work) that `$sp - 0` is 8-byte aligned, which happens not to be true.

Comment: You can use  `sdc1` / `s.d` to store a 64-bit `double` from a pair of `$f` registers.  Your current code only copies and stores the low 32 bits of the `double` with `mfc1` and `sw $t0, 0($sp)` .  See http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~langer/273/12-notes.pdf.  (It only mentions `swc1` for storing a single word from one `$f` register.)  Note that loading/storing doubles as two 32-bit halves avoids the need for 8-byte alignment; it's only your `ldc1` that's requiring that.